# Merge and append dataframe, fill with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames that I want to merge on 'Id'. The two data frames are not the same size, and Id may be repeated in either one. I'd like the columns to merge in df1 for the first instance of each Id, and then have the data table appended for instances that don't match.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Id": [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4],
                     "x": [3, 7, 8, 3, 5, 4, 1]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Id": [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4],
                     "y": [9, 7, 5, 8, 9, 6, 8]})
```

Expected output:

```
df1 = {"Id": [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4],
"x": [3, 7, 8, NaN, NaN, 3, 5, 4, 1],
"y": [9, NaN, 7, 5, 8, 9, 6, 8, NaN]} 
}
```

EDIT: Expanding the solution into my larger dataset results in error: 'float' object not iterable.

All Dates columns are datetime and UserId and ActivityCount are int64.

```
df = (
    pd.concat(
        [df_emails.groupby("UserId")["Email Dates"].agg(list), df_emails.groupby("UserId")["Click Dates"].agg(list), 
         df_emails.groupby("UserId")["Open Dates"].agg(list), df_activity.groupby("UserId")["Activity Dates"].agg(list), 
         df_activity.groupby("UserId")["ActivityCount"].agg(list)],
        axis=1,
    )
    .reset_index()
    .apply(
        lambda x: [
            (x["UserId"], *t) for t in zip_longest(x["Email Dates"], x["Click Dates"], x["Open Dates"], 
                                                   x["Activity Dates"], x["ActivityCount"], fillvalue=np.nan)
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
    .explode()
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .rename(columns={0: "UserId", 1: "Email Dates", 2: "Click Dates", 3: "Open Dates", 4: "Activity Dates", 5: "ActivityCount"})
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


df = (
    pd.concat(
        [df1.groupby("Id")["x"].agg(list), df2.groupby("Id")["y"].agg(list)],
        axis=1,
    )
    .fillna("")
    .apply(list)
    .reset_index()
    .apply(
        lambda x: [
            (x["Id"], *t) for t in zip_longest(x["x"], x["y"], fillvalue=np.nan)
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
    .explode()
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .rename(columns={0: "Id", 1: "x", 2: "y"})
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    Id    x    y
0  1.0  3.0  9.0
0  1.0  7.0  NaN
1  2.0  8.0  7.0
1  2.0  NaN  5.0
1  2.0  NaN  8.0
2  3.0  3.0  9.0
3  4.0  5.0  6.0
3  4.0  4.0  8.0
3  4.0  1.0  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. However, when I apply it to my larger dataset, column x in df1 has NaN's initially, which appears to result in an error. I tried replacing Nan with a blank, which doesn't help. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @mkp Can you edit your question and put there small df1/df2 that is causing problem? I tried to run my code with `df1['x']` set to all `NaN` and it worked.

Comment: It might be a different issue. I also got it to work with NaN's in the smaller dataset.  I expanded the code in the edit and added the error output.

Comment: @mkp I've updated my answer. Added `.fillna("").apply(list)` to prevent the `NaN` values appearing